# Freeze and restore a Cocoa task or thread?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-management

Just wondering..

Let's say I start an external application using `NSTask` or `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:` or something else in a Cocoa application (I am thinking on OSX, but iOS may also help).

I know it is possible to stop this task and resume it.

But.. is it possible to save all memory information used by that task, save to disk, and restore it in the future?

In case it is possible, how? Where to begin? Is there any project available that provides such feature? Any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Saving all of memory is technically possible: It's called a core dump. I don't know whether you can trigger one programmatically, but that is a thing that exists. The hard part is restoring memory (IIRC, some older UNIXes let you exec a core dump, but I wouldn't be surprised if OS X never got that feature or disallows it), the would-be-mighty-impressive-if-you-pulled-it-off part would be restoring the states of all threads (and making sure timers behave as if the machine had been asleep), and the impossible part is reconnecting file descriptors and other connections.

Comment: Thanks Peter, very informative. Do you know if are there any simple examples in C/C++ for small applications or is this feature part of the OS potential capabilities? I am thinking in something like an emulator. Some video-game emulators can save the state of the console, I suppose I can try the same in a normal application with less information, right? Thanks again!

Comment: An emulator *is* the machine that the guest OS/program/game is running on; the guest machine's memory is simply a `malloc`ked buffer within the emulator process, so for the emulator to save that out to a file on the host machine is no differently than for any other program to save out any other buffer. Dumping the entire memory of *your own process* is an altogether different task, and I don't know how to do that specifically. Check “Mac OS X Internals” by Amit Singh—if any book would have that info, that one would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible on the Mac OS X kernel.

For what it's worth, Linux has *experimental* support for this functionality (known as [Linux Checkpoint/Restart](https://ckpt.wiki.kernel.org/)). The implementation is utterly specific to the Linux kernel, though, and cannot be ported to Mac OS X short of a complete rewrite.